# Prevent jumping when pattern matching

Tags: search, jump, pattern

Is there a way to prevent cursor to search forward when using the `*` or `/`?

I just want to highlight the word I am on & others, but not move to forward nor backward.

Comment: This question has an accepted answer [over there at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256697/vim-search-and-highlight-but-do-not-jump).

Answer (score 4):

This will do for the `*` search, I'm not sure how to do that for `/`.

```
nnoremap <silent> * :let @/= '\<' . expand('<cword>') . '\>' <bar> set hls <cr>
```

`@/` is the search register, which we set to `<cword>`, the word under the cursor, surrounded by words boundaries `\<` `\>` to match actual words rather than parts of words.

`g*` matches even "non words". We can adapt it as well :

```
nnoremap <silent> g* :let @/=expand('<cword>') <bar> set hls <cr>
```

For visual mode:

```
vnoremap * y/\V<C-R>=escape(@",'/\')<CR><CR>
```

This copies the selection into the unnamed register `@"` (`:h registers`), starts a search with its content, backslashes escaped, via the `:h expression register` (inserted with `<C-R>=`).